# Creating an array of threads or thread pool in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a single threaded model job which iterates over a collection of data and customizes the data. I want to divide the collection into small sublists and want each individual sublist to be executed in parallel. Should I use an array of threads (where the size of the array is the number of sublist created), or a thread pool?

Comment: Threadpool, hands down.

Comment: `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);` or `Executors.newCachedThreadPool();` are your friends.

Comment: Yes, don't reinvent the wheel.  Use a ThreadPool.

Comment: Thanks all, but the single thread that I am speaking is not application thread. Its one of the thread from Kafka(a total of 8 Kafka consumer threads runnning) which consumes a collection of data. Now I need to wait this Kafka thread , for all sublist to finish processing. Can I do it with a thread pool ? I was planning to use array of threads and CountDownLatch for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are going to divide the collection further? If your type of jobs/data are same then let them be in one collection and threads from threadpool will pick up the task from the list and run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks. I want to break the one collection into sublist. One collection contains 1000 json data.  I cannot iterate over this collection and keep on processing each and every json.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use thread pool in any case, because in this case you can get rid of low level operations for managing arrays of objects and increase flexibility.

You should use **ExecutorService** instance in your code and choose right type of it.
**For example:**

1. Executors.newCachedThreadPool - if your processing logic is simple enough and doesn't require much processing time (to not produce too many concurrent threads that will cause different exceptions).
2. Executors.newFixedThreadPool - if your processing logic is complex enough, so you should limit number of threads.

So, I think that you should:

1. Create required ExecutionService in your consumer.
2. Go through your collection and submit processing job to executor (for each element, instance of Callable). Save them in `List<Future<?>>` instance.
3. Iterate through futures (wait completion of all tasks), save results in new collection, send results somewhere and commit kafka offset.